# Which preposition to use with injury nouns?

Tags: prepositions

I was reading a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Memphis_Three) that has this line:

> Christopher Byers had lacerations **to** various parts of his body

It made me wonder if the preposition **on** would work as well. Intuitively I thought when people discover a body, they see the injuries such as cuts and bruises **on** it. It also made me think about other similar nouns: **cut, blow, injury, bruise, wound**. After doing some research on dictionary sites, Google Books and Google Ngram, this matter has become ever more confusing to me.

Google Ngram suggests that "injuries **to**" is much more common than "injuries **on**". But I have found several attestations of "injuries **on**"

> Autopsy reports showed that the baby had blunt force trauma injuries **on** the head and neck. ([source](https://www.chron.com/news/houston-texas/houston/article/Man-charged-with-murder-in-2011-death-of-12866648.php))

Both **on** and **to** seem to follow "laceration", "blow", and "wound" as in these sentences from the Oxford Dictionaries, Google Dictionary and Google Books results:

> ‘Small lacerations **on** the face usually heal well with this preparation.’
>
> ‘he suffered lacerations **to** his head and face’
>
> "a blow **on** the head"
>
> "he received a blow **to** the skull"
>
> ‘a wound **to** the thigh’
>
> Groups of six trees each were treated with the various dressings, two wounds **on** each tree being protected while two others were left untreated to serve as checks. ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=hxNGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22wounds%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxopKJjPzaAhWHc98KHb46ADYQ6AEISjAG))
>
> Attending to the Wounds **on** Christ's Body. (It's a book title)
>
> ‘blood ran from a cut **on** his jaw’
>
> ‘He smiles at her and she smiles back then continues to clean the cut **on** his shoulder.’
>
> ‘He sustained minor injuries of slight cuts and scratches **to** his head.’
>
> ‘She had goose bumps all over her body and a bruise **on** her arm.’
>
> ‘They suffered bruises and injuries **to** their heads.’

Are there any differences in meaning? Which preposition in preferred? Would the original sentence work equally fine as

> Christopher Byers had lacerations **on** various parts of his body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is generally *active* vs. *passive* wounding.  Someone causes a wound *to* a body part (active), while you can have a wound *on* a body part (passive).

Which you use depends on context:

> The assailant inflicted a number of lacerations **to** the victim's arms and torso.
>
> The victim has a number of lacerations **on** his arms and torso.

You can shift this the passive voice, but the preposition still indicates some kind of *action*:

> A number of lacerations were inflicted **to** the victim's arms and torso (by the assailant).

or

> The victim received lacerations **to** his arms and torso (from the assailant).

To put it another way:  In general, use *to* when referring to an *action* that causes a wound, and use *on* when referring to a *situation* where a wound exists.

Keep in mind this is only a rough guide, not a rule.  Some people will prefer one over the other, or switch it up based on what sounds best to them.